# Does there exists $f\in A(\mathbb T)$ such that $||f||=r$ and $||\mathrm{e}^{if}||= \mathrm{e}^{r}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb T)$ and define the Fourier coefficient of $f$ : $\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\, \mathrm{e}^{-int} dt; (n\in \mathbb Z)$.Consider the space,
 $$A(\mathbb T):= \{f:\mathbb T \to \mathbb R : \hat{f}\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z), \  \text {that is,} \  \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty \}.$$
$A(\mathbb T)$ is normed by the $L^{1}-$ norm on $\mathbb Z$:
$$||f||= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty; \ \text {for} \ f\in A(\mathbb T). $$
We also note that $A(\mathbb T)$ is a Banach algebra under pointwise addition and multiplication.

Fix $r\in (0, \infty)$, and let $f\in A(\mathbb T)$ such that $||f|| \leq r$; and so, $\mathrm{e}^{if}\in A(\mathbb T)$ and $||\mathrm{e}^{if}||\leq \mathrm{e}^{||f||}\leq \mathrm{e}^{r}$.

**My question are**: (1) Does there exists $f\in A(\mathbb T)$ such that $||f||=r$ and $||\mathrm{e}^{if}||= \mathrm{e}^{r}$ ? (2) Otherwise, How to we get a sequence $(f_{n})\subset A(\mathbb T)$ with $||f_{n}||\leq r$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} ||\mathrm{e}^{i  f_{n}}||= \mathrm{e}^{r}$ ?

**Edit**:(Note that if we allowed complex valued functions in $A(\mathbb T)$; then the answer is given below by prof. Y S)

---

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for a non-constant function?

Comment: Also, please refresh my memory: does pointwise multiplication work nicely with $\|\cdot\|$, or do we use convolution instead?

Comment: Thanks prof. J. Y;  this space actually a Fourier algebra and  point wise multiplication will work nicely there; and I am looking for real valued functions; even real constant functions will be fine; thanks;

Comment: BTW: This is the [Wiener Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_algebra) if you want to find more references elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Question $(1)$. Try $f(t)=-i$ (a constant function).

Comment: Thanks, prof. Y S; I agree your example will work; But, actually, I was looking for real value functions in $A(\mathbb T)$; which I forgot to mention  in it; which now I am editing it; please have look; thanks a lot;